# Show chat messages for specific post id

Tags: node.js, express

Currently I wanted to show chat messages that are from the specific tournament post id, this is how I do it but I didn't manage to show it based on the tournament post id. Is there something I am missing? Or because my routes is /chat didn't pass the req.params.id of the specific tournament post?

**UPDATE** (chat endpoints)

```
app.get('/chat', function(req, res){
    Tournament.findById(req.params.id, function(err, tournament){
        Message.find({tournament:req.params.id}, function(err, messages){
            res.send(messages)
        })
    })
});
app.post('/chat', function(req, res){
    let message = new Message(req.body)
    message.save((err)=>{
        if(err){
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        else{
            io.emit('message', req.body)
            res.sendStatus(200)
        }
    })
})
```

(jquery)

```
$(()=>{
  const socket = io()
  $('#send').click(()=>{
    let message  = {
      tournament: $('#tournament').val(),
      name: $('#name').val(),
      message: $('#message').val()
    }
    postMessage(message)
  })
  getMessages()
  socket.on('message', addMessage)

  function addMessage(message){
    $('#messages').append(`<div class='container-chat'><div id='container-inline'><h6>${message.name}:</h6> <p>${message.message}</p></div></div>`)
  }
  function getMessages(){
    $.get('http://localhost:3000/chat', (data)=>{
      data.forEach(addMessage);
    })
  }
  function postMessage(message){
    $.post('http://localhost:3000/chat', message)
  }
})
```

(tournament.pug)

```
                            input#tournament.form-control.input-sm.chat_input(type='hidden', placeholder='Tournament Id', value=tournament._id)
                            input#name.form-control.input-sm.chat_input(type='hidden', placeholder='User Username', value=user.username)
                            span.input-group-btn
                            input#message.form-control.input-sm.chat_input(type='text', placeholder='Type message')
                            span.input-group-btn
                            button#send.btn.btn-outline-secondary.btn-sm Send
```

(MessageSchema)

```
let MessageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    tournament:{
        type: String
    },
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    message:{
        type: String
    },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Comment: Your `message.find` method seems to be passing an empty object to it so I'm assuming it just fetches everything. Maybe you need to pass the tournament id to it. It would be good to see the code behind `Message.find()`

Comment: Thats all the code for my endpoints inside my app.js file, I dont know what else code of Message.find( ) here?

Comment: Are you using a database to story these messages in? I'm assuming `Message` is a model of some sort? If so you probably need to pass parameters into it to filter by tournament id.

So this line in `app.get('/')` - `Message.find({})` should be something like `Message.find({tournament:req.params.id}, function(err,messages) {`

Comment: Yes Message is the model for all the chat messages stored, inside the schema contains fields like tournament which stores the tournament id everytime a user submit a message, and a user field that reference to the user username and a message field for all the content of the message sent.

Comment: See my updated comment. At the moment you aren't passing in any filters by which to find messages, so it will get all of them. I'm assuming you're using mongodb and a quick glance at the docs shows you how to use the find method with filters https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Comment: You mean '/chat' ?

Comment: yes I do mean /chat sorry

Comment: I tried your approach but none messages shown for based on the specific tournament post id. I assume maybe the routes /chat doesnt pass in any values of tournament id ?

Comment: Yes you're correct there actually. It should be app.get('/chat/:id'....

Comment: I updated the routes to /chat/:id as well as inside my jquery code but still not working. Any ideas why? Haha quite confused rn why it wont show up, feels like Im doing the correctly but maybe I missed something tho..

Comment: I console.log(tournament) from Tournament.findById(tournament) it returns undefined. It seems like the req.params.id not even passing at the first place for routes /chat/:id

Comment: Have you updated your client side jquery code for the $.get to include the id? $.get(“/chat/123”) for example?

Comment: Yes I updated the jquery code get url to http://localhost:3000/chat/:id

Comment: You must use an actual Id in the jquery code and not the string “:id”

Comment: Like this? $.get('http://localhost:3000/chat/'+tournament.id)

Comment: This is getting a bit difficult without more context and the limited space of comments. Can you share the routing code for the actual page the user visits? I think you need to read up a bit more on urls and routes tbh

Comment: Sure, lets move this in a discussion chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201725/discussion-between-ecksdee-and-tommybs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amend your script file to the following: you were missing the correct parameter ids and the 'http' on your urls.

```
$(()=>{
const socket = io();

$('#send').click(()=>{
let message = {
tournament: $('#tournament').val(),
name: $('#name').val(),
message: $('#message').val()
}
postMessage(message)
})
getMessages()
socket.on('message', addMessage)

function addMessage(message){
$('#messages').append(`<div class='container-chat'><div id='container-inline'><h6>${message.name}:</h6> <p>${message.message}</p></div></div>`)
}
function getMessages(){
$.get('http://localhost:3000/chat' + $('#tournament').val(), (data)=>{
data.forEach(addMessage);
})
}
function postMessage(message){
$.post('http://localhost:3000/chat', message)
}
})
```